# Why does str.lower() modify modify string comp

Tags: python, string, comparison

I have the following python code snipped and have been getting insane as i don't understand why I'm getting these different results. Can anyone elaborate?

````
   test = "GTX1050Ti 4GB"

print(test)

if "gtx" and "560" and "ti" in test:
    print("GTX 560 Ti")
else:
    print("nope")
    
print(test.lower())

if "gtx" and "560" and "ti" in test.lower():
    print("GTX 560 Ti")
else:
    print("nope")``` 

Output:

GTX1050Ti 4GB
nope
gtx1050ti 4gb
GTX 560 Ti
````

Comment: Use `"gtx" in test and "560" in test and "ti" in test` and `"gtx" in test.lower() and "560" in test.lower() and "ti" in test.lower()` which is the correct way and you will see that both expressions are false.

Comment: ... i feel so stupid sorry for that. Is there a more "elegant" way of doing this?

Comment: You need to understand that when you add `and` you're separating the conditional into chunks to evaluate. So you're checking the boolean of a non-empty string "gtx", the boolean of a non empty string "560" and **then** checking if "ti" is in test. The boolean of a non-empty string is `True`, so it's not checking what you're hoping it's checking for.

Comment: elegant way: `all(x in test for x in ['gtx', '560', 'ti'])`

Comment: thank you! This is honestly an embarassing mistake should have know better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `all` to help ensure the condition is met for all checks

```py
checks = ['gtx', '560', 'ti']
if all(check in test for check in checks):
    ....

if all(check in test.lower() for check in checks):
    ....
```

Then if you need to change what is checked, you only need to do it in once place.

Comment: Brackets are redundant.